# Recover from PendingRollbackError and allow subsequent queries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

- We have a `pyramid` web application.
- We use `SQLAlchemy@1.4` with Zope transactions.

In our application, it is possible for an error to occur during flush [as described here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/sessions.html#this-session-s-transaction-has-been-rolled-back-due-to-a-previous-exception-during-flush-or-similar) which causes any subsequent usage of the SQLAlchemy session to throw a `PendingRollbackError`. The error which occurs during a flush is unintentional (a bug), and is raised to our exception handling view... which tries to use data from the SQLAlchemy session, which then throws a `PendingRollbackError`.

Is it possible to "recover" from a `PendingRollbackError` if you have not framed your transaction management correctly? The SQLAclhemy documentation says to avoid this situation you essentially "just need to do things the right way". Unfortunately, this is a large codebase, and developers don't always follow correct transaction management. This issue is also complicated if savepoints/nested transactions are used.

```
def some_view():
    # constraint violation
    session.add_all([Foo(id=1), Foo(id=1)])
    session.commit()  # Error is raised during flush
    return {'data': 'some data'}


def exception_handling_view():  # Wired in via pyramid framework, error ^ enters here.
    session.query(... does a query to get some data)  # This throws a `PendingRollbackError`
```

I am wondering if we can do something like the below, but don't understand `pyramid` + `SQLAlchemy` + Zope transactions well enough to know the implications (when considering the potential for nested transactions etc).

```
def exception_handling_view():  # Wired in via pyramid framework, error ^ enters here.
    def _query():
        session.query(... does a query to get some data)

    try:
        _query()
    except PendingRollbackError:
        session.rollback()
        _query()
```

Comment: Should `PendingRollbackError` cause a HTTP request retry few times until it fails permanently?

Comment: @aaron the problem is that it is a legacy codebase and transactions and savepoints are not consistently used--and new developers don't know how to use them. Also, exceptions are not properly handled so unhandled exceptions can lead to a nested transaction bypassing a rollback (if a context manager is not used).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to execute your query, just try to get the connection:

```py
def exception_handling_view():
    try:
        _ = session.connection()
    except PendingRollbackError:
        session.rollback()

    session.query(...)
```

`session.rollback()` only rolls back the innermost transaction, as is usually expected — assuming nested transactions are used intentionally via the explicit `session.begin_nested()`.

You don't have to rollback parent transactions, but if you decide to do that, you can:

```py
while session.registry().in_transaction():
    session.rollback()
```